# second Hdd on optical bay and power consuption

Tags: hard-drive, power-management

I have a new Lenovo W541, and while the first week the fully charged battery was saying 4 hours left", after I added 1T HDD on the optical bay (DVD slot) now it says 2 hours left. I read around that the second HDD can drain battery. Is there a way to reduce the spinning speed of HDD on battery?

Comment: Why do you want to reduce the spinning speed of the HDD?  It is going to draw basically the same amount of power to function.  I assume you meant "speed" when you used the non-existent word "spid"

Comment: Yeah thanks I corrected speed. I have read online that reducing the spinning speed would reduce power consuption, but maybe its not true.